# unable to run darkice on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm doing a project on live audio streaming using Icecast and darkice using raspberry pi. I configured icecast server darkice successfully on ubuntu.

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.t3node.com/blog/live-streaming-mp3-audio-with-darkice-and-icecast2-on-raspberry-pi/) as my reference.

I followed the same steps on my raspberry pi, but unfortunately darkice is not configured successfully. When I start darkice an error occurs :

```
DarkIce: DarkIce.cpp:1187: can't open connector [0]
```

I don't know what it means? How can I investigate and solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Reading the source, it seems like the sound card can't be opened. The tutorial you point to uses a USB sound card, defined in the `[input]` section of `darkice.cfg`.

Try replacing

```
device        = hw:1,0
```

with

```
device        = hw:0,0
```

While you're at it, I'd recommend to get the latest upstream version, which fixes a nasty bug with remote Icecast servers:

```
$ svn checkout http://darkice.googlecode.com/svn/darkice/trunk/ darkice-1.3
$ cd darkice-1.3
$ cp -R ../darkice-1.0/debian .
$ dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -us -b
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you've killed any instance of darkice that's already running quietly in the background before trying to run it again.

Comment: I got the same error but on a different scenario, I managed to run darkice once after the pi booted, but when I tried to stop it and restart it, the error occurred.
So I used this command 'ps -aux | less' to find all running processes, and then looked for the running darkice process, killed it, restarted darkice 'sudo darkice' and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same message (the number after connector is important, although I dont know how and what) while testing on a guest network somewhere. In my case it was the fact that darkice could not connect to the server port 8048 which was defined and prescribed by streampartner.nl. Changing to port 8000 to reach my own icecast server (with port 8000 forwarded on my router) had no problems with the rest of the .cfg file exactly the same. And the same wireless networking hardware. The message had nothing to do with the audio definition.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this. When I start darkice with a television connected the external USB adapter is device 2.
But after removing the HDMI connector, the USB adapter suddenly is device 1

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/433584)

Comment: It looks like you have a different question or situation. Please open a new question if that is the case.